# what is the behavior of java after returning to a synchronized block after notify on an object

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I know that after we invoked a `wait()` on an object, the lock of that object will release to permit another thread to give that lock by a synchronized block and invoke `notify()`.
before we entered the synchronized block that we have called `wait()` method, we acquire the lock and invoke the `wait()`.

but after `wait()` the method release the lock.

now my question is after we invoke `notify()` in another thread, does the thread that is waiting on that object acquire the lock again.

below is a simple code for this:

```java
Object obj = new Object();
        synchronized (obj) {
            try {
                obj.wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            afterWait();
        }
```

is the lock of object acquire when jvm executes `afterWait()` method or not because it is also in a synchronized block.

Comment: What does the javadoc of Object.wait() say?

Comment: they said: Causes the current thread to wait until it is awakened, typically

Comment: Well, read the remaining of the javadoc. It contains your answer (see below). It's really as simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Javadoc of `wait()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()) (emphasis added):

> The current thread must own this object's monitor. The thread releases ownership of this monitor and waits until another thread notifies threads waiting on this object's monitor to wake up either through a call to the notify method or the notifyAll method.  **The thread then waits until it can re-obtain ownership of the monitor and resumes execution.**

Comment: it seems that it will acquire the lock again.

Answer (score 3):

In Java, monitors are implemented according to Mess' semantics. It implies that when current thread needs to wait, it releases the monitor and joins the other waiting threads to get the monitor once again. The written example is not safe, as wait should be in a loop with checking some condition to wait again, as Java does not guarantee that thread will be woken up only in the case of `notify()` or `notifyAll()` methods. It may work on your development environment but fail on another one. Also, `notify()` method does not guarantee that thread will wake up and get the lock as it may not get the signal, so it is safe to do `notifyAll()` to awake all threads waiting for the lock.

I am new to Stack Overflow, so I am not sure if my shared knowledge is straight to the question or no.